# How to set minimum days between selected start and end day on daterange picker?

Tags: date-range, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I tried to use [this](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) date range picker.

Default is 0 days, which means a client can select start and end days to be the same day. Can I somehow define to end the day can be a minimum of one day ahead, for example, client select start day as today and min end day mus be tomorrow or someday before tomorrow?

```
$('.input-daterange').daterangepicker({
        minDate: moment().subtract(30, 'd').toDate(),
        locale: {
            format: 'MM.DD.YYYY.'
        }
    });
```

I tried to use startDate, EndDate, MindaDate... but nothing helps :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, You can't.
There are several issues on the github page referencing this: [github issues](https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/issues/2145)

It is possible to fork the library and add this feature in yourself or add in an additional event which you can listen to.

The pull request [here](https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/pull/1424/files) is adding this feature so you could use that.